# How to install sox for PyTorch audio?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, audio, python

I want to run PyTorch code on Linux. I start a virtual machine on AWS with AMI `Deep Learning PyTorch`, but, surprisingly, PyTorch is not installed. So I run:

```
python3 -m pip install torch torchaudio
```

When I load a WAV file, I get this error:

```
RuntimeError: Couldn't find appropriate backend to handle uri /path/to/file.wav and format None.
```

Reading [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62543843/cannot-import-torch-audio-no-audio-backend-is-available), I install sox:

```
python3 -m pip install sox
```

but I get the same error. Reading [this thread](https://github.com/pytorch/audio/issues/3539), I test this code:

```
import torchaudio
print(torchaudio.utils.sox_utils.list_read_formats())
```

and I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension/utils.py", line 207, in wrapped
    _init_sox()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension/utils.py", line 70, in _init_sox
    _load_lib("libtorchaudio_sox")
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension/utils.py", line 64, in _load_lib
    torch.ops.load_library(path)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_ops.py", line 852, in load_library
    ctypes.CDLL(path)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/ctypes/__init__.py", line 374, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: libsox.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torchaudio/_extension/utils.py", line 209, in wrapped
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: list_read_formats requires sox extension which is not available. Please refer to the stacktrace above for how to resolve this.
```

so I install `sox` with:

```
sudo apt-get install -y sox
```

and I confirm that it works:

```
$ which sox
/usr/bin/sox
```

I restart the Python3 REPL, and the virtual machine too, and I get the same errors.

How can I install sox for use with PyTorch audio?

Comment: It seems you are missing libsox.so. Can you find this file on your system? Perhaps it is called libsox.so.3 or something similar, in that case make a symlink so that libsox.so also exists. You can also try running sudo ldconfig

Comment: @C-nan No, I can't find `libsox.so` with `find / -type f -name libsox.so`, nor with `find / -type f -name libsox.so.3`. And yet `sox` is installed with version `SoX v14.4.2`.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue you need to install libsox-dev package

```
sudo apt install libsox-dev
```

This solution worked for me on ubuntu

Comment: Problem solved.